# Need help with Verilog Card Counter

Tags: verilog, vivado

So basically the buttons work and such but in my second always loop, it skips the if statement that turn on led_light when >=2 but it turns on the led i have programed for >=5 when I press the button 5 times. If anyone can help fixing my if statement that would be awesome.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module card_algo(clk, posb, negb, led_light, led_big,reset);
input clk;
input posb;           //count up button
input negb;           //count down button
output reg led_light; //led represents light bet
output reg led_big;   //led represents big bet
integer count = 0 ;    //count 
input reset;

wire btn0_state, btn0_dn, btn0_up;
    debounce upcount (
        .clk(clk),
        .btn_input(posb),
        .output_state(btn0_state),
        .output_ondn(btn0_dn),
        .output_onup(btn0_up)
    );
    wire btn1_state, btn1_dn, btn1_up;
    debounce downcount (
        .clk(clk),
        .btn_input(negb),
        .output_state(btn1_state),
        .output_ondn(btn1_dn),
        .output_onup(btn1_up)
    );


 always @ (posedge clk) 
 begin : ButtonPress
    if (btn0_up == 1)
    begin 
       count <= count + 1;
    end      //if up button is pressed, count is raised
    else if (btn1_up==1)
       count <= count - 1;;
 end

always @ (posedge clk) 
begin: Lights
  if (  count >= 2)
  begin
    led_light =1;
  end
  if (count >=5)
    led_big=1; 
  else
    led_big=0; led_light=0;

end

endmodule
```

Comment: When should `led_light` be 0? As written it will always be 0 because it's assignment to zero is outside any conditional statements. Also  `led_light` and `led_bit` should be assigned with non-blocking assignments.

Comment: Have you tried doing it "the wrong way" as suggested by section three in this article? https://wiki.cs.astate.edu/images/Jeff.jenness-CS4-5133-How_(not)_to_Code_a_Finite_State_Machine.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
begin: Lights
  // ...
  if (count >=5)
    led_big=1; 
  else
    led_big=0; led_light=0;  // <---- Problem here
```

Verilog doesn't care how you indent or space your code.
Just because you put  `led_big=0;` and `led_light=0` on the same line doesn't make them both part of the else clause. Without a `begin` and `end` around them, as far as Verilog is concerned your code is the same as

```
begin: Lights
  // ...
  if (count >=5)
    led_big=1; 
  else
    led_big=0; 
  led_light=0;
```

Now is it more clear that `led_light` is assigned to 0, regardless of the value of `count`?

Avoiding this kind of error is why you see many Verilog code examples that use `begin` and `end` for every clause in an if statement, even if there is only one statement in a clause.